# Using Django URLs with AngularJs routeProvider

Tags: javascript, python, angularjs, django

for a project, I am using Django on the back-end and AngularJs on the front end.

Basically, what I want is to run the Angular app only when the url starts with `projectkeeper/`.

In other words, lets say my website is example.com. I want the angular app to run for the URLs `example.com/projectkeeper/dashboard/`, `example.com/projectkeeper/projects/` and so on, but not on `example.com/about/`.

Hope I have made myself clear. Anyway, in order to do this, I am doing the following with my code:

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^projectkeeper/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='base.html')),
]
```

In the template **base.html**, I refer to my angular app obviously. For the angular routing, I have done the following:

```
myapp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/dashboard/', {
            title: 'Dashboard',
            controller : 'DashboardController',
            templateUrl : 'static/app_partials/projectkeeper/dashboard.html'
        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo : '/' });
}]);
```

So, ideally, what I thought was that going to `example.com/projectkeeper/#/dashboard/` would run the DashboardController from my angular app. However, this is not the case, I only get an empty page which means the routing was incorrect.

Any solutions to this? As I said before, I want is to run the Angular app **only** when the url starts with `projectkeeper/`.

Comment: do you have your static files defined correctly?

Comment: Yep, static files work fine. The controllers are loaded properly. The URL pattern is the problem.

Comment: you should check the browser's console for error as well i think. It's better to trace back what went wrong

Comment: Can you please post the `base.html` code? That's where the problem is going to be. I've done this in a number of projects and I have it working exactly the way you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're pretty close, there is few things to make this works(honestly, this is confusing to understand and I hope I didn't forget anything).

First, your URLs order is important, if you define something before the angular routes they will be rendered first, so use your django app's urls **before** the angular one.

Then, if you want to make angular know about the sub-path you need to define `<base>` tag in your header. In your case:

`<base href="/projectkeeper/" />`

(you can also define `projectkeeper`it in all of your `where` functions tho).

For the urls, I would change the regex to: `r'^projectkeeper/.*'`. Again, should be the last one in your urls list.

You will encounter other issues like the  `{{ }}`, authentication issues, but those will stay for a different answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try out this ui router for angularJS 
https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

It will be more helpful on nested views and problem like which you are facing currently.